# Kubectl rollout restart for statefulset

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-statefulset

As per the [kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#rollout), `kubectl rollout restart` is applicable for deployments, daemonsets and statefulsets. It works as expected for deployments. But for statefulsets, it restarts only one pod of the 2 pods.

```
✗ k rollout restart statefulset alertmanager-main                       (playground-fdp/monitoring)
statefulset.apps/alertmanager-main restarted

✗ k rollout status statefulset alertmanager-main                        (playground-fdp/monitoring)
Waiting for 1 pods to be ready...
Waiting for 1 pods to be ready...
statefulset rolling update complete 2 pods at revision alertmanager-main-59d7ccf598...

✗ kgp -l app=alertmanager                                               (playground-fdp/monitoring)
NAME                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alertmanager-main-0   2/2     Running   0          21h
alertmanager-main-1   2/2     Running   0          20s
```

As you can see the pod alertmanager-main-1 has been restarted and its age is 20s. Whereas the other pod in the statefulset alertmanager, i.e., pod alertmanager-main-0 has not been restarted and it is age is 21h. Any idea how we can restart a statefulset after some configmap used by it has been updated?

[Update 1] Here is the statefulset configuration. As you can see the `.spec.updateStrategy.rollingUpdate.partition`  is not set.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"monitoring.coreos.com/v1","kind":"Alertmanager","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"alertmanager":"main"},"name":"main","namespace":"monitoring"},"spec":{"baseImage":"10.47.2.76:80/alm/alertmanager","nodeSelector":{"kubernetes.io/os":"linux"},"replicas":2,"securityContext":{"fsGroup":2000,"runAsNonRoot":true,"runAsUser":1000},"serviceAccountName":"alertmanager-main","version":"v0.19.0"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-02T07:17:49Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    alertmanager: main
  name: alertmanager-main
  namespace: monitoring
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: Alertmanager
    name: main
    uid: 3e3bd062-6077-468e-ac51-909b0bce1c32
  resourceVersion: "521307"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/monitoring/statefulsets/alertmanager-main
  uid: ed4765bf-395f-4d91-8ec0-4ae23c812a42
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      alertmanager: main
      app: alertmanager
  serviceName: alertmanager-operated
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        alertmanager: main
        app: alertmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config/alertmanager.yaml
        - --cluster.listen-address=[$(POD_IP)]:9094
        - --storage.path=/alertmanager
        - --data.retention=120h
        - --web.listen-address=:9093
        - --web.external-url=http://10.47.0.234
        - --web.route-prefix=/
        - --cluster.peer=alertmanager-main-0.alertmanager-operated.monitoring.svc:9094
        - --cluster.peer=alertmanager-main-1.alertmanager-operated.monitoring.svc:9094
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        image: 10.47.2.76:80/alm/alertmanager:v0.19.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /-/healthy
            port: web
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 3
        name: alertmanager
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9093
          name: web
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9094
          name: mesh-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9094
          name: mesh-udp
          protocol: UDP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /-/ready
            port: web
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 3
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 200Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/alertmanager/config
          name: config-volume
        - mountPath: /alertmanager
          name: alertmanager-main-db
      - args:
        - -webhook-url=http://localhost:9093/-/reload
        - -volume-dir=/etc/alertmanager/config
        image: 10.47.2.76:80/alm/configmap-reload:v0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: config-reloader
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 25Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/alertmanager/config
          name: config-volume
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
      serviceAccount: alertmanager-main
      serviceAccountName: alertmanager-main
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: alertmanager-main
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: alertmanager-main-db
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
status:
  collisionCount: 0
  currentReplicas: 2
  currentRevision: alertmanager-main-59d7ccf598
  observedGeneration: 4
  readyReplicas: 2
  replicas: 2
  updateRevision: alertmanager-main-59d7ccf598
  updatedReplicas: 2
```

Comment: could you provide your statefulset YAML? I think that problem might be related to `Partition strategy` https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#partitions Also output of `kubectl rollout status sts alertmanager-main` might be helpful here.

Comment: As of September 2020 the problem still persists. `kubectl rollout restart sts ...` works for a HelloWorld stateful set, but not for prometheus or alertmanager stateful sets managed by `prometheus-operator`. This is probably due to some prometheus-operator magic, which interfers with the `rollout restart` implementation?

Comment: @geekQ Good to know that I'm not the only one facing this issue

Answer (score 12):

You did not provide whole scenario. It might depends on [Readiness Probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) or `Update Strategy`.

`StatefulSet` restart pods from index `0 to n-1`. Details can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/).

**Reason 1***

`Statefulset` have 4 [update strategies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#update-strategies).

- On Delete
- Rolling Updates
- Partitions
- Forced Rollback

In `Partition` update you can find information that:

> If a partition is specified, all Pods with an ordinal that is greater
>   than or equal to the partition will be updated when the StatefulSet’s
>   `.spec.template` is updated. All Pods with an ordinal that is less
>   than the partition will not be updated, and, even if they are deleted,
>   they will be recreated at the previous version. If a StatefulSet’s
>   `.spec.updateStrategy.rollingUpdate.partition` is greater than its
>   `.spec.replicas`, updates to its `.spec.template` will not be
>   propagated to its Pods. In most cases you will not need to use a
>   partition, but they are useful if you want to stage an update, roll
>   out a canary, or perform a phased roll out.

So if somewhere in `StatefulSet` you have set `updateStrategy.rollingUpdate.partition: 1` it will restart all pods with index 1 or higher.

Example of `partition: 3`

```
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-0   1/1     Running   0          30m
web-1   1/1     Running   0          30m
web-2   1/1     Running   0          31m
web-3   1/1     Running   0          2m45s
web-4   1/1     Running   0          3m
web-5   1/1     Running   0          3m13s
```

**Reason 2**

Configuration of `Readiness probe`.

If your values of `initialDelaySeconds` and `periodSeconds` are high, it might take a while before another one will be restarted. Details about those parameters can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes).

In below example, pod will wait 10 seconds it will be running, and `readiness probe` is checking this each 2 seconds. Depends on values it might be cause of this behavior.

```
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 2
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

**Reason 3**

I saw that you have 2 containers in each pod.

```
NAME                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alertmanager-main-0   2/2     Running   0          21h
alertmanager-main-1   2/2     Running   0          20s
```

As describe in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase):

> `Running` - The Pod has been bound to a node, and all of the Containers have been created. At **least one Container is still running**, or is in the process of starting **or restarting**.

It would be good to check if everything is ok with both `containers` (readinessProbe/livenessProbe, restarts etc.)

Comment: I've updated the post with the alertmanager statefulset yaml. `.spec.updateStrategy.rollingUpdate.partition` is not set. So I don't think reason 1 is applicable. Reason 2 also seems to be not applicable since the `kubectl rollout status` command shouldn't have mentioned that rollout is complete. I tried doing the `kubectl rollout restart` on the stateful set again before posting here and waited for 8 mins and only one pod got restarted.

Comment: Regarding reason 3, I've observed that both the pods are ready(as per kubectl describe) and also the ui is opening up on both these pod ips as expected. So they don't seem to unhealthy as well.

Comment: In this case I've observed the behaviour with the prometheus alertmanager statefulset. Maybe I'll try to reproduce the issue with a simpler example like nginx.

Comment: I couldnt reproduce your issue based on your YAML (with nginx image). Any updates?

Comment: I tried doing a rollout restart of another statefulset prometheus. It worked as expected and both the prometheus pods got restarted. But still for the alertmanager statefulset, only 1 pod is getting restarted. I've installed these components in the k8s cluster using the mixin kube-prometheus. I'll try removing some parts of the alertmanager deployment to identify the issue.

Comment: @livinston any updates? This issue occurs only with this one image?

Answer (score 6):

You would need to delete it. Stateful set are removed following their ordinal index with the highest ordinal index first.

Also you do not need to restart pod to re-read updated config map. This is happening automatically (after some period of time).

Comment: If we have to delete the pod in a statefulset to restart the pod, then I think the docs regarding the rollout restart command seem to be misleading.

I'm not sure if updated config maps are automatically re-read unless the application is coded in that way. In this case the alertmanager reads the configuration in startup which is passed as a command line argument.

Comment: Yes, correct, application should anticipate to re-read mounted configMap volume, but from infrastructure perspective ConfigMap is updated, i.e. files in volume are updated. That is achieved using and updating symbolic links (done by k8s) within mounted drive/directory.
I believe your pod is not updated due to lack of resource. Ideally they should be updated starting from highest ordinal index one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to your `ownerReferences` definition. You can try it without any owner and do the rollout again.